# Expressão em português para algo "possible, but not feasible"

Tags: expressões, estrangeirismos, tradução-inglês

Recentemente ouvi a expressão em inglês *possible, but not feasible* indicando que algo pode ser feito, ainda que inviável ou pouco provável que ocorra. No [English Language & Usage SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226740/feasible-possible-or-potential-solution) a diferença entre estes termos já foi discutida.

Para traduzi-la no Português pensei em *possível, mas não factível (ou fazível)*, porém o [Dicionário Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/fact%C3%ADvel) coloca *possível* como sinônimo de *factível* e *fazível* e eu busco um termo que indique a possibilidade de ocorrência como remota.

Existe uma expressão em português que deixe claro que não é impossível que algo ocorra, mas não é provável?

Comment: *Possível mas não fazível* ;)

Comment: Fazível também é dado como sinônimo de _factível_ e _possível_ no Priberam. Vou atualizar a questão com esta informação.

Comment: No inglês também são sinónimos :http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/feasible

Comment: O que não quer dizer que não se possa usar a expressão.

Comment: O único (suposto) problema que vejo com "Possível, mas não factível" é o facto de "possível" aparentemente ser sinónimo de factível. No entanto isto não é um problema porque palavras serem sinónimas não implica de forma alguma que sejam intercambiáveis em todas em circunstâncias. A título de exemplo considere-se o termo "[impossível](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/impossivel)" que admite como sinónimos  tanto "incrível" como "intolerável". Não é preciso dizer mais nada.

Comment: @GitGud muito bem explicado, faz uma resposta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Possível, mas inviável

*Not Feasible* pode ter várias traduções, mas "inviável" é a que mais faz sentido num português brasileiro.

Comment: Acho que não tem nada de mal com a expressão que ele usou e só por isso não dou +1. Mas gostei desta variante, embora não ache que seja uma expressão muito utilizada como a versão em Inglês.

Comment: @JorgeB. Aqui só usam esta.

Comment: Sim, mas usam como expressão no dia a dia? Pronto já dei +1 :)

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim, como tradução não-literal.

Answer (score 5):

Há vários significados para [feasible](http://pt.bab.la/dicionario/ingles-portugues/feasible#tr): possível, viável,   exequível,  provável,  praticável e factível; e ainda, entre outros, concretizável. Assim sendo, **dependendo do contexto, a expressão *possible, but not feasible*, pode traduzir-se de várias formas**. Duas ainda não mencionadas serão:

- **possível,  mas impraticável**; e
- **possível, mas não concretizável**.

Por exemplo:

> Uma solução (teórica) **possível, mas impraticável** (no estado de desenvolvimento atual).

E **poderá,  claro, ser traduzida de forma menos literal**, como em alguns dos exemplos mencionados no link acima.

*Adicionado*.

A ideia, referida no seu comentário à resposta de Ricardo, de que "algo tem baixa probabilidade de ocorrer, mas não é impossível"  pode simplesmente ser expressa por "algo é improvável".

Answer (score 4):

O único (suposto) problema que vejo com "Possível, mas não factível" é o facto de "possível" aparentemente ser sinónimo de "factível". No entanto isto não é um problema porque palavras serem sinónimas não implica de forma alguma que sejam intercambiáveis em qualquer circunstância.

A título de exemplo considere-se o termo "[impossível](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/impossivel)" que admite como sinónimos  tanto "incrível" como "intolerável".

De qualquer forma, a mim, que falo português de Portugal, parece mais natural a expressão "Possível, mas não viável".

Comment: *português de Portugal  ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. xD Sim, eu já tinha decidido que esse era o termo que ia usar. Saiu-me.

Answer (score 3):

Possível, mas não **exequível**!!!

Comment: Não consigo me acostumar com a remoção do trema por conta do último acordo ortográfico. Exequivel no lugar de exeqüivel parece escrito errado...